# Recuperar informacion de un archivo json filtrando por un campo

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, spyder

Estoy tratando de trabajar con un archivo JSON, quiero recorrer el archivo y recuperar la población de cada país, en el caso que `'Year' == '2010'`.

```
import json

# Load the data into a list.
filename = 'data_json.json'

with open(filename) as f:
    pop_data = json.load(f)

#print(json.dumps(pop_data, indent=2))

#print(len(pop_data))

for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] =='2010':
        nombre_pais = pop_dict['Country Name']
        poblacion_pais = pop_dict['Value']
        print (nombre_pais + ": " + poblacion_pais)
```

Output:

```
runfile('C:/~/Data_json/worl_population1.py', wdir='C:/~/Data_json')
```

Este es un fragmento del JSON que intento leer:

> ```
> [
>    {
>       "Country Code": "ZWE",
>       "Country Name": "Zimbabwe",
>       "Value": 1.5411675E7,
>       "Year": 2014
>    },
>    {
>       "Country Code": "ZWE",
>       "Country Name": "Zimbabwe",
>       "Value": 1.5777451E7,
>       "Year": 2015
>    },
>    {
>       "Country Code": "ZWE",
>       "Country Name": "Zimbabwe",
>       "Value": 1.6150362E7,
>       "Year": 2016
>    }
> ]
> ```

Comment: ¿Podrias agregar el JSON en cuestión o un fragmento representativo del mismo para crear un [mcve]?

Comment: Mira no se como adjuntar el *.json, asi que te paso un fragmento[ {
    "Country Code": "ZWE",
    "Country Name": "Zimbabwe",
    "Value": 15411675.0,
    "Year": 2014
  },
  {
    "Country Code": "ZWE",
    "Country Name": "Zimbabwe",
    "Value": 15777451.0,
    "Year": 2015
  },
  {
    "Country Code": "ZWE",
    "Country Name": "Zimbabwe",
    "Value": 16150362.0,
    "Year": 2016
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando `json.load` (o `json.loads`) carga una archivo idénticamente igual a como convierte `[]` a `list` y `{}` a `dict`, parsea cada dato al tipo correspondiente de Python. Es decir, los valores asociados a `Año` los convierte a `int` y los asociados a `Value` los convierte a `float`.

Esto hace que la comparación `if pop_dict['Year'] =='2010':` nunca se evalúe como verdadera, porque, de existir, estaría comprobando la igualdad entre `2010` y `"2010"` (`int` y `str`) lo cual siempre va a ser falso.

Por otro lado no puedes hacer:

```
nombre_pais + ": " + poblacion_pais
```

porque `poblacion_pais` es un entero, debes hacer el casting explícito a `str` antes:

```
nombre_pais + ": " + str(poblacion_pais)
```

aunque mejor usa formateo de cadenas, es más legible y eficiente.

El código quedaría:

```
import json

# Load the data into a list.
filename = 'data_json.json'

with open(filename) as f:
    pop_data = json.load(f)

for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] == 2010:
        nombre_pais = pop_dict['Country Name']
        poblacion_pais = pop_dict['Value']
        print(f"{nombre_pais}: {poblacion_pais}")
```

Puede que te interese pasar también el año como argumento al script, en ese caso puedes hacer:

```
import argparse
import json


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Muestra la población por paises en un año determinado'
    )
parser.add_argument('year', metavar='year', type=int,
                    help='el año por el que filtrar'
                    )

args = parser.parse_args()
year = args.year


# Load the data into a list.
filename = 'data_json.json'

with open(filename) as f:
    pop_data = json.load(f)

for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] == year:
        nombre_pais = pop_dict['Country Name']
        poblacion_pais = pop_dict['Value']
        print(f"{nombre_pais}: {poblacion_pais}")
```

> ```
> >>> runfile('C:/~/Data_json/worl_population1.py', wdir='C:/~/Data_json', args="2010")
>
> Zimbabwe: 15777451.0
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias me aduvo perfecto!!!